# How to restrict typescript's literal expression to accept only available property?

Tags: typescript

This is a very simple question.

```
const foo = {
    "a" :1,
    "b" :2,
    "c" :3
}

const foo2 = {
    "a":1,
    "c":2
}

const foo3:typeof foo2 = {...foo}
```

Now foo3 has a property called b. But `typeof foo2` dose not have property "b", I would like to prevent this. By config typescript.

I know i can solve this problem with `object assign`, but i can't use `object assign` in situations where only the type is defined and there is no object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) and declare the keys you want to have.

E.g.

```
type aType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
const foo: {[key in aType]: number} = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3 
};

const foo2: {[key in aType]: number} = {
  'a': 1,
  'c': 3 
};

const foo3: typeof foo2 = {...foo}
```

Now the code above should throw you something like

```
Property 'b' is missing in type etc.. etc..
```

Comment: this will help me a lot  : )